# "None" string appear after print a line in python

Tags: python, sorting

I a new in python programming. Today I practice with sorting a list. 
I've got a strange output with this code:

```
# problem 13
def lensort(list):
   list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
   print list 

print "Sort by length: ", lensort(['python', 'perl', 'java', 'c', 'haskell','ruby'])
```

The output is:

```
Sort by length:  ['c', 'perl', 'java', 'ruby', 'python', 'haskell']
None
```

So, I have no idea the reason why "None" is shown in 2nd line.
Could anyone help to about this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `lensort` doesn't return anything in particular, so it returns `None`.  Change the `print` in `lensort` to `return` and it will get rid of the `None`

Comment: Welcome to Python. First comment: Don't name variables `list`. There is a function by that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are printing the list at the end of `lensort` function instead of returning it. A function in Python implicitly returns `None` if it doesn't `return` anything explicitly.

```
def lensort(list):
    list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
    return list
```

By the way, you can simplify the key function passed as follows: `list.sort(key=len)`

Also, avoid using class names as a variable name such as `list`, `set`, `dict` or `object`:

```
def lensort(lst):
    ...
```

Comment: also, do not use `list` as a variable name, shadows a built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost double printing the list so to speak. You don't want to print in the function since you're already calling `print` right after it. Instead you'll want to `return` the list and then have the `print` function print the returned list when you call `lensort`.

Here's a corrected version that should hopefully clarify what I mean:

```
# problem 13
def lensort(list):
   list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
   return list 

print "Sort by length: ", lensort(['python', 'perl', 'java', 'c', 'haskell','ruby'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.sort` method sorts a list in place. You do not return its return. Also, no `lambda` needed:

```
>>> li=['python', 'perl', 'java', 'c', 'haskell','ruby']
>>> li.sort(key=len)
>>> li
['c', 'perl', 'java', 'ruby', 'python', 'haskell']
```

If you want a new sorted list, use the `sorted` function:

```
>>> sorted(['python', 'perl', 'java', 'c', 'haskell','ruby'], key=len)
['c', 'perl', 'java', 'ruby', 'python', 'haskell']
```